# How to create automount map with LDAP

Tags: ldap, nis

I need to create an automount map for a particular location in our environment with the ldap as we have "ldap+nis" integrated setup. I don not know much about the ldap+NIS hence require your help to understand it... 
The ldif file format which i got it from the env example is as follows..

```
dn: cn=/depot,nisMapName=auto_master_lnx_noida,ou=automount,ou=Default,ou=noida,
 ou=services,o=example.com
nisMapName: auto_master
objectClass: nisObject
objectClass: top
cn: /depot
nisMapEntry: ldap:automountMapName=auto_depot,ou=automount,ou=Default,ou=noida,o
 u=services,o=example.com
```

Similarly i need create the following auto.master , we are using sun ldap

```
/lan/ttv auto_lan_ttv
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, they would look something like:

```
dn:automountMapName=auto_direct,dc=nishpind
objectClass: top
objectClass: automountMap
automountMapName: auto_direct


dn:automountKey=/mnt_direct/test1,automountMapname=auto_direct, dc=nishpind
objectClass: top
objectClass: automount
automountInformation:hostA:/tmp 
automountKey: /mnt_direct/test1

dn:automountKey=/mnt_direct/test2,automountMapname=auto_direct, dc=nishpind
objectClass: top
objectClass: automount
automountInformation:hostB:/tmp
automountKey:/mnt_direct/test2
```

Although somewhat dated, there is some information at:
https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAPAutomountInformation

-jim